# Identifying a font

Tags: fonts

What is the font used in these diagrams? I tried searching, but can't find exact one.

EDIT: www.identifont.com gives me "Chalfont Light" as a result, but this is not the font on diagrams.

[image]

Comment: See also: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2330/should-we-post-a-catch-all-question-answering-whats-this-font-on-tex-sx And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: After some tries I got [Neutra Text with Identifont](http://www.identifont.com/list?17+id+10+ETM+2+GOH+2+COW+2+BSF+2+COU+2+COY+2+31IA+3+569+3+GOK+3+OEF+3+FRN+3+205J+3+31YA+3+3467+3+31IB+4+31I9+4+GSJ+4+31Y9+4+2RG+5+5GM+7+4DO+7+62D+8+2AA+8+30X+9+5IO+10).

Comment: That font is the right answer. @Heiko Oberdiek If you'd like, you can enter it as the answer to this question.

Comment: @VividD: The closing is sometimes a little fast for my taste. Let's hope, the question can be reopened.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: The post is still a duplicate, as Identifont is discussed as a general approach to finding fonts. Generally, this type of question is off-topic (or unrelated to TeX - LaTeX).

Comment: @Werner: The closing has prevented writing an answer that fits to *this* question, but not to the duplicate. Also I was unable to find the font with the answers of the duplicate, because I had to answer two questions of identifont differently than I would have expected to get the chance for finding the font.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: True. Duplicates don't always have to be _exact_ duplicates. You mentioned the font was found via Identifont and that "technique" is discussed in the referenced source. Similarly, we don't provide answers to every "?ow do I get this symbol?" question, since there's [How to look up a symbol or identify a math alphabet?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/5764) which describes a generic way of finding it. Finally, the suggested duplicate stemmed from [Should we post a catch-all question answering “What's this font?” on TeX.SX?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2330/5764)